# Translating equivalent formulas in to code isn't giving correct results

Tags: java, math, language-agnostic

I'm trying to calculate the Mean Difference average of a set of data. I have two (supposedly equivalent) formulas which calculate this, with one being more efficient (O^n) than the other (O^n2).

The problem is that while the inefficient formula gives correct output, the efficient one does not. Just by looking at both formulas I had a hunch that they weren't equivalent, but wrote it off because the derivation was made by a statician in a scientific journal. So i'm assuming the problem is my translation. Can anyone help me translate the efficient function properly?

Inefficient formula: [image]

Inefficient formula translation (Java):

```
    public static double calculateMeanDifference(ArrayList<Integer> valuesArrayList)
    {
        int valuesArrayListSize = valuesArrayList.size();
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < valuesArrayListSize; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < valuesArrayListSize; j++)
                sum += (i != j ? Math.abs(valuesArrayList.get(i) - valuesArrayList.get(j)) : 0);
        }

        return new Double( (sum * 1.0)/ (valuesArrayListSize * (valuesArrayListSize - 1)));
    }
```

Efficient derived formula: [image]

where (sorry, don't know how to use MathML on here):

- x(subscript i) = the ith [order statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistics) of the data set
- x(bar) = the mean of the data set

Efficient derived formula translation (Java):

```
public static double calculateMean(ArrayList<Integer> valuesArrayList)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int valuesArrayListSize = valuesArrayList.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < valuesArrayListSize; i++)
        sum += valuesArrayList.get(i);

    return sum / (valuesArrayListSize * 1.0);
}

public static double calculateMeanDifference(ArrayList<Integer> valuesArrayList)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double mean = calculateMean(valuesArrayList);
    int size = valuesArrayList.size();

    double rightHandTerm = mean * size * (size + 1);
    double denominator = (size * (size - 1)) / 2.0;

    Collections.sort(valuesArrayList);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += (i * valuesArrayList.get(i) - rightHandTerm);

    double meanDifference = (2 * sum) / denominator;

    return meanDifference;
}
```

My data set consists of a collection of integers each having a value bounded by the set [0,5].

Randomly generating such sets and using the two functions on them gives different results. The inefficient one seems to be the one producing results in line with what is being measured: the absolute average difference between any two values in the set.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my translation?

**EDIT:** I created a simpler implementation that is O(N) provided the all your data has values limited to a relatively small set.The formula sticks to the methodology of the first method and thus, gives identical results to it (unlike the derived formula). If it fits your use case, I suggest people use this instead of the derived efficient formula, especially since the latter seems to give negative values when N is small).

Efficient, non-derived translation (Java):

```
public static double calculateMeanDifference3(ArrayList<Integer> valuesArrayList)
{
    HashMap<Integer, Double> valueCountsHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();

    double size = valuesArrayList.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int currentValue = valuesArrayList.get(i);

        if(!valueCountsHashMap.containsKey(currentValue))
            valueCountsHashMap.put(currentValue, new Double(1));
        else
            valueCountsHashMap.put(currentValue, valueCountsHashMap.get(currentValue)+ 1);
    }

    double sum = 0;

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> valueCountKeyValuePair : valueCountsHashMap.entrySet())
    {
        int currentValue = valueCountKeyValuePair.getKey();
        Double currentCount = valueCountKeyValuePair.getValue();

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> valueCountKeyValuePair1 : valueCountsHashMap.entrySet())
        {
            int loopValue = valueCountKeyValuePair1.getKey();
            Double loopCount = valueCountKeyValuePair1.getValue();

            sum += (currentValue != loopValue ? Math.abs(currentValue - loopValue) * loopCount * currentCount : 0);
        }
    }

    return new Double( sum/ (size * (size - 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation of `sum += (i * valuesArrayList.get(i) - rightHandTerm);` is wrong, it should be `sum += i * valuesArrayList.get(i);`, then after your `for`, `double meanDifference = ((2 * sum) - rightHandTerm) / denominator;`

Both equations yields about the same value, but they are not equal. Still, this should help you a little.

Comment: Thanks! I feel very stupid. I actually tried fiddling around with the order in the way you presented, but it still yielded wacky results. It works now, however!

Comment: Incidentally, your implementation of the inefficient formula is even more inefficient than it needs to be because `valuesArrayList.get(i) - valuesArrayList.get(j)` will be 0 when `i == j`, so the condition is needed.

Comment: @MRAB: Not quite sure what you're getting at. There is a conditional expression testing for that which surrounds that statement

Comment: @Kevin: What I mean is that when `i == j`, `valuesArrayList.get(i) - valuesArrayList.get(j)` will give the same result as `valuesArrayList.get(j) - valuesArrayList.get(j)`, so `(i != j ? Math.abs(valuesArrayList.get(i) - valuesArrayList.get(j)) : 0)` gives the same result as `Math.abs(valuesArrayList.get(i) - valuesArrayList.get(j))`.

Comment: @MRAB Ah I see. Yes, I suppose the condition is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You subtract `rightHandTerm` on each iteration, so it gets [over]multiplied to N.

The big Sigma in the nominator touches only (i x_i), not the right hand term.

One more note: `mean * size == sum`. You don't have to divide sum by N and then remultiply it back.